# MySQL python connector| executemany() and an alternative fails to perform

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm trying to quickly insert large number of rows into the following table:

```
    CREATE TABLE word
                (word_id int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                 word_txt VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE)
```

**using executemany() :**

```
query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO word (word_txt) VALUES (%s)"
try:
   self.cursor.executemany(query,word_list)
except ...
```

word_list is a list of single string tuples.
e.g: word_list = [('cases',), ('regard',), ('disregard',), ...]

Interface Error returns at execution: "No result set to fetch from".

**using an alternative:**

```
query = f"INSERT IGNORE INTO word (word_txt) VALUES {words}"
try:
    self.cursor.execute(query)
except
```

according to MySQL the syntax is invalid after execution.
same as before words is a list of of single string tuples.
the value of (string) variable "query" at the moment of debugging:

```
query = INSERT IGNORE INTO word (word_txt) VALUES [('tire',), ('object',), ('really',), ...,('these',), ('regarded',)]
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I don't think that error can come from this code. It would come from a call like `self.cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: @Barmar , Sure: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\database.py", line 233, in testing_words
    self.cursor.executemany(query, word_list)
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 962, in executemany
    self.fetchall()
  File "...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 999, in fetchall
    raise errors.InterfaceError("No result set to fetch from.")

I'm not using fetchall (), at least not directly.

Comment: This seems like a MySQL Connctor bug to me. It shouldn't try to fetch anything from an INSERT query.

Comment: Are you reusing a cursor that was previously used for a `SELECT` query? Try creating a new cursor.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow (it's night time over here). but any idea why the syntax is wrong on the alternative solution?

Comment: Try `print(query)` to see what it looks like, and you should see the SQL syntax errors.

Comment: I actually wrote it in my post. last row. don't see the issue.

Comment: You can't have `[]` around all the values in SQL, you can't have `,` at the end of a list.

Comment: It should be `VALUES ('tire'), ('object'), ...`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I had a bit of mix-up. If you'll write an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I don't have a solution. Your original code seems like it should have worked, the connector is supposed to replace the placeholder properly.